# Font oddity - is this a bug?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, truetype-fonts

I have Windows 7 Ultimate Home Edition, installed some new fonts recently (I do graphic design etc.) and have noticed some of them don't display in Windows/Fonts via the control panel, **Appearance and Personalization**. And when they do occur they always have `FONTNAME_0.ttf` (is this always common for TTF files?).

I have 1306 fonts according to FontFrenzy but it doesn't show all of them via the **Appearance and Personalization** control panel.

Also, in `C:\Windows\Fonts`, the fonts only show as the file name, e.g. `arial.ttf` (but for some odd reason `arial_0.ttf` appears, same for other fonts).

Why is this, and anyone else had this problem before!

Comment: How did you install the fonts?

Comment: The usual way in Windows 7, clicking on "Install" from the font file.

Answer (score 0):

I hardly know any real facts about the topic, but I thought I'd share my thoughts for what it's worth.

### How Windows stores Fonts

To my understanding, every font sub-type (as distinguished by the [font characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font#Font_characteristics)) is stored in a single file on Windows (or, at least, it **can** be). This can lead to a bit of confusion. Let's look at an example.

[image: Example Windows 7 Font List]
As you can see, the **Adobe Heiti Std R** font (first on the second row) is visualized by single paper sheet with **Abg** on it. This is a single font, representing a single font file.
In contrast, the **Arial** font (last on the third row) is visualized by **3** sheets of paper. This means it's a **font family** consisting of multiple font files (which provide the same font but with differing characteristics).

[image]

However, this does not explain any `_0` file names. Those exist for a different reason.

### So where do the names come from?

Here is a directory listing I just did a minute ago:

```
C:\Windows\Fonts>dir aria*
2011-05-11  00:34           778,552 arial.ttf
2011-01-17  01:32           749,004 arialbd.ttf
2011-01-17  01:32           561,924 arialbi.ttf
2011-01-17  01:32           555,884 ariali.ttf
2006-07-14  12:01           173,936 ARIALN.TTF
2006-07-14  12:01           178,864 ARIALNB.TTF
2006-07-14  12:01           178,316 ARIALNBI.TTF
2006-07-14  12:01           179,368 ARIALNI.TTF
2002-11-18  18:44        23,275,812 ARIALUNI.TTF
               9 File(s)     26,631,660 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  163,335,311,360 bytes free
```

As you can see, no `_0` files exist by default.

Now, if I copy `arial.ttf` to my desktop, right-click it and select **Install**, the following dialog will pop up:
[image]

Now, you **should** click **No**! If you don't, this is the result:

```
C:\Windows\Fonts>dir aria*
2011-05-11  00:34           778,552 arial.ttf
2011-01-17  01:32           749,004 arialbd.ttf
2011-01-17  01:32           561,924 arialbi.ttf
2011-01-17  01:32           555,884 ariali.ttf
2006-07-14  12:01           173,936 ARIALN.TTF
2006-07-14  12:01           178,864 ARIALNB.TTF
2006-07-14  12:01           178,316 ARIALNBI.TTF
2006-07-14  12:01           179,368 ARIALNI.TTF
2002-11-18  18:44        23,275,812 ARIALUNI.TTF
2011-05-11  00:34           778,552 ARIAL_0.TTF
              10 File(s)     27,410,212 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  163,332,550,656 bytes free
```

Please note, that I now have a file called `ARIAL_0.TTF`.

So, when you were importing those fonts, you might have brought some system fonts along. Obviously, Microsoft and I slightly differ in our definitions of the term "*replace*".