# Why is the text (font) showing or displaying all in italics?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, fonts

I just restarted Chrome, and now all kinds of elements on all websites are emphasized:

[image]
[image]

What is going on? This even applies to system menus, not just web sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I broke my fonts when I prepared my answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/408968/font-oddity-is-this-a-bug/408998#408998).

My Arial font was gone and substituted with Arial Italic. Re-installing Arial fixed the issue. It was just a coincidence that Chrome used Arial for the rendering of the test in question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's Chrome - pop open an IE window, go to www.google.com and do a search for 'chrome everything is emphasized' - you'll see the same thing.

It's the Google results.

I understand the emphasis on the search terms, and I suspect that the word 'all' is emphasized because it's related to the search term 'everything'.

Yes. If I change the search in IE to 'chrome something is emphasized' then the word 'all' is no longer emphasized in the results. So it's doing a sort of thesaurus thing to figure out what to emphasize in search results.

I don't see any way to turn that off in the Google search settings. I expect there isn't any way to do so.